# Prestashop content only link not working

Tags: php, prestashop

I've got the terms and conditions link and added Fancybox to it, however it comes up with the entire web page, not just the content in the fancy box container when you click the link.

The link is in the format site/online-store/au/content/3-terms-and-conditions-of-use?content_only=1

however the content_only=1 doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: Do you have any js-errors in the developer console during ajax-request?

Comment: No errors that I can see. The content all loads, but it's the entire page (header, footer etc)

Comment: Does content only mode work outside of Fancybox, when you try to load page directly 3-terms-and-conditions-of-use?content_only=1 in browser?

Comment: Hey, Nope it still loads the entire page. I've resorted to injecting a query in the function and spitting out the terms of service manually, not ideal though.

Comment: Do you use overrided run() method? It contain the code: if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className)))
    $this->initHeader();

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this link is loading a non-https content from an https page.

To fix it, edit controllers/front/ParentOrderController.php

```
$this->link_conditions = $this->context->link->getCMSLink($cms, $cms->link_rewrite, false);
```

and change last parameter to true to force the use of https

```
$this->link_conditions = $this->context->link->getCMSLink($cms, $cms->link_rewrite, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the CMS you load doesn't have the required parameters. Thus, the condition in

> /controllers/front/CmsController.php

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Tools::getValue('content_only') && $id_cms && Validate::isLoadedObject($this->cms) && in_array($id_cms, array((int)Configuration::get('PS_CONDITIONS_CMS_ID'), (int)Configuration::get('LEGAL_CMS_ID_REVOCATION')))) 
{
  $this->ssl = true;
}
```

Returns false. just replace this with

```
 $this->ssl = true;
```

Tada...

Answer (score 0):

**This will work for PrestaShop 1.6.x/1.7.x and will open the ToS in a Fancybox**

In your controller:

```
$cms = new CMS(Configuration::get('PS_CONDITIONS_CMS_ID'), $this->context->language->id);
$conditions_link = $this->context->link->getCMSLink($cms, $cms->link_rewrite).'?content_only=1';
$this->addJqueryPlugin(array('fancybox'));
$this->context->smarty->assign(['conditions_link' => $conditions_link]);
```

Then, in your .tpl file:

```
<a class="fancybox-tos" href="{$conditions_link}">{l s='Terms of service' d='Shop.Theme.Checkout'}</a>
```

And finally, in your .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox-tos').fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            autoDimensions: false,
            autoSize: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!